# What are the three types of languages of the scriptures?

Tags: scripture, identification-request

In a book I got mention of the three types of languages used in scriptures:

> samAdhi-bhasha prathmA loukiki_iti tathA parA/ tritiyA parakiyapA_ iti shastrabhasha tridhA smrita//

Meaning : There are three types of languages of a scripture: Samadhi language, Loukiki language and ParakiyA Language.

What are the implications of these three types of languages as per the scriptures?